# HTML/Javascript login, 'userName' variable not working in login code portion

Tags: javascript, html

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE> Username Generator </TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <style>
    //: the code below was adapted from w3schools (dropdown code)
    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {   
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }

    .show {
      display:block;
    }

    //: the code above was adapted from w3schools
  </style>
  <BODY>
    <h2>Username Generator</h2>
    <script>
      var userName = ""
      var fName = ""
      var lName = ""
      var age = ""
      var flname = ""
      var flNameAge = ""
      var lfName = ""

      function prompts() {
        fName = window.prompt("please enter your first name")
        lName = window.prompt("please enter your last name")
        age = window.prompt("please enter your birth year (in 'yy' form not 'yyyy' form)")

        genUsers()
      }

      function genUsers() {
        flName = fName + lName;
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = flName;

        flNameAge = flName + age;
        document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = flNameAge;

        lfName = lName + fName;
        document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML = lfName;

        lfNameAge = lName + fname + age;
        document.getElementById("lage").innerHTML = lfNameAge
      }

      function flNameClick() {
        userName = flName;
        alert(userName + " is your new username, try it out");
      }

      function flNameAgeClick() {
        userName = flNameAge;
        alert(userName + " is your new username, try it out");
      }

      function lfNameClick() {
        userName = lfName;
        alert(userName + " is your new username, try it out");
      }

      function checkLogin(x) {
        if ((x.id.value != userName)||(x.pass.value !="123")) {
          alert("Invalid Login");
          return false;
        }
        else
          alert("Congrats you have logged in")
      }

      //: the code below was adapted from w3schools
      function dropdown() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
      }

      window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
          var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
          var i;

          for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
              openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
          }
        }
      }
      //: the code above was adapted from w3schools
    </script>
    <form>
      <p>UserID:<input type="text" name="id"></p>
      <p>Password:<input type="password" name="pass"></p>
      <p><input type="button" value="Login" onClick="checkLogin(this.form)"></p>
      <input type="button" value="Click Here To Generate Username" onClick="prompts()">
    </form>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="dropdown()" class="dropbtn">Username Choices</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a id="name" onClick="flNameClick()"> CLICK</a>
        <a id="age" onClick="flNameAgeClick()">GEN</a>
        <a id="lname" onClick="lfNameClick()">BUTTON</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

So far, everything works as desired except for the final portion where the 'userName' variable changes to whichever option you choose in the drop down menu, from there, you should be able to use the new variable input as a written login. my problem is that this variable is not being accepted as a valid written login after it is defined. I believe this error occurs in the function checkLogin(x) and in the first portion of code in the  tag as that is where the variable 'userName should be carried over. I do not know why this variable doesn't work as intended and I am in desperate need of help. please advise.

Comment: Mate you need to learn JS first. `;` is what you are missing. Please have a good read for declaring variables ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Much of your code is unnecessary to your problem, has a tonne of whitespace, and isn't formatted. Doing this will make it easier for others to assist.